# Optional parameter passed python script

Tags: python, variables, nameerror, option-type

I have a simple python script that takes three parameters -f  -l  -a .  I want the -a to be an optional parameter, is using a try/except the most efficient way to achieve this ( I guess I need to catch the exception if they do not pass the required parameters too)?   Here is the script, thanks in advance:

---

```
try:
    (options, args) = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'f:l:a:', ['first=', 'last=', 'age='] )

except getopt.GetoptError:
    help()

for option in options:

        if option[0] == '-f':
                firstName = option[1]
        elif option[0] == '-l':
                lastName = option[1]
        elif option[0] == '-a':
                personAge = option[1]

if (firstName is None):
    print >>sys.stderr, "Missing first name"
    sys.exit(1)

if (lastName is None):
    print >>sys.stderr, "Missing first name"
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    (personAge is None)
except NameError:
    print("Setting personAge to unknown")
    personAge = 'Unknown'

print firstName + " " + lastName + " " + personAge
```

Comment: Do you think that making bold and creating large font made your question more urgent?

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades just approved a pending edit.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the philosophy of **opt** ional vs positional arguments in Python documentation first.

Try looking at the [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) module. Its API is more flexible, if you still want to do this.

Comment: "Required options are generally considered bad form because users expect options to be optional, and thus they should be avoided when possible"
http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#required